# Best practise to put enums in mvc app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC app with really lot of enumerations. What would be the best practise for organizing enumeration inside MVC project. Inside model class, create separate class for enums, ...?

Comment: its good to have a separate class for enums..

Comment: Can you give some examples of the kind of enum's you're talking about. Are they logically grouped or completely unrelated. Are they type indexes or simple numbers? If they are so numerous you might even be better off adding the types into a database.

Comment: Enumerations are somehow connected, first has 20 different categories of occupations, second has 6 levels of education...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC isn't really any different from any other .NET technology in this respect.

In general, there's no need to nest enums inside a class - just put them into a suitable namespace that's related to their purpose.  If the purpose is limited to one or a few classes, put it in the same namespace and project as these classes.

If an enum is only ever used by a single class, you *could* nest the enum type in the class, but there's little benefit.